# Error xcopy /Y path exited with code 4 VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I copied solution from my c:\ drive to d:\ drive and solution not run gives

```
xcopy /Y path exited with code 4 VS2015
```

Comment: Anything in your pre or post build events?

Comment: There were a found a wrong dll path, resolved the issue .